# Kafka sink from multiple independent brokers

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I want to aggregate changes from multiple databases into one so I thought to run a Debezium connector and a Kafka server/broker next to each database, and use a Kafka sink connector to consume from all those Kafkas to write into one database.

The question is, can I use a single instance of Kafka sink connector to consume at the same time, from multiple Kafka brokers which are independent (not a cluster).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Running a Kafka broker next to each database sounds very complicated. And a single Kafka connect worker that connects to different Kafka broker clusters does not seem to be supported, as far as I can see.

If you go down this path, it may make more sense to use something like Kafka [MirrorMaker](https://cwiki.apache.org/confluence/display/KAFKA/Kafka+mirroring+%28MirrorMaker%29) to copy your local topics to a single main Kafka cluster, and then use a Kafka Connect Sink to read all the copied topics from one worker and write to a central DB.

Ultimately, running a Broker next to each source database is pretty complicated. From what you described, it sounds like you have some connectivity between your different databases, but it is limited and possibly prone to disconnects. Have you considered alternative designs:

- DB Replication: Use your DB vendor's native async replication to just copy the data to a single target DB. The remote region is always read-only, replication should not slow down your source DB (depends on the DB, of-course). And async DB replication can usually handle some network disconnections and latency.
- Local Debezium: Run a process with Debezium next to each DB, and save all events to a file. Copy the files to some central server or to a cloud storage service like S3. Finally, import these files into a central DB. This would basically skip Kafka completely.

Answer (score 0):

You can point the Connect property files at whatever bootstrap.servers you want

The property itself is required to be part of a single "cluster" (even if a single broker), which would be determined by the broker zookeeper.connect property

Comment: Thanks for the reply, but from the Connect doc [link](https://kafka.apache.org/documentation/#connectconfigs_bootstrap.servers), it seems that it works when bootstrap.servers are all in a single cluster. Should I add all the brokers to a cluster when they capture different databases?

Comment: You don't need one broker per database. Each Connector will write to its own set of topics, which get replicated across several brokers

Comment: The reason I use a broker on each database is because I'm dealing with physical machines and poor network connectivity so I want to make sure the changes from each database are captured when network fails or some parts of the system shutdown (in a local broker that's always reachable to it's db) and when network is up again, the changes are available to the sink from the relevant broker...

Comment: If you have poor network connectivity, you shouldn't expect a distributed Kafka or Connect cluster to work either, or even a Kafka client to remotely consume from your brokers, so I suggest you focus on fixing those issues